# What am I doing wrong in my assembly code?

Tags: solidity, yul

This function doesn't work if I put amountOut variable in it. Can't understand why.

```
function swap(
    address token,
    address pair,
    uint256 amountIn,
    uint256 amountOutMin,
    uint256 tokenOutNo,
    address router,
    address[] calldata path
) public {
    uint256 amountOut = getAmountOut(router, path, amountIn, amountOutMin);

    assembly {
        mstore(0x7c, ERC20_TRANSFER_ID)
        // destination
        mstore(0x80, pair)
        // amount
        mstore(0xa0, amountIn)

        let s1 := call(gas(), token, 0, 0x7c, 0x44, 0, 0)
        if iszero(s1) {
            // WGMI
            revert(3, 3)
        }

        mstore(0x7c, PAIR_SWAP_ID)
        switch tokenOutNo
        case 0 {
            mstore(0x80, amountOut)
            mstore(0xa0, 0)
        }
        case 1 {
            mstore(0x80, 0)
            mstore(0xa0, amountOut)
        }

        // address(this)
        mstore(0xc0, address())
        // empty bytes
        mstore(0xe0, 0x80)

        let s2 := call(gas(), pair, 0, 0x7c, 0xa4, 0, 0)
        if iszero(s2) {
            revert(3, 3)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Nothing, just says execution reverted